# How to get SpeechKit and AVCaptureDevice to work with each other

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I am using SpeechKit from Nuance to transcribe text from video as I record it.  However, when SpeechKit is active, AVAudioSession generates the following error:

```
AVAudioSession.mm:646: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
```

Disabling SpeechKit lets me record and preview the video.  Enabling it generates the transcribed text, but doesn't record the video.

I have put a sample project online at:

https://github.com/jeffreality/iOSVideoTranscriber

My goal is to save the video with audio, as well as have a transcription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the following line to viewDidLoad:

```
#if ENABLE_TRANSCRIPTION

[SpeechKit setupWithID:@"Your ID"
                  host:@"dfo.nmdp.nuancemobility.net"
                  port:443
                useSSL:NO
              delegate:nil];
#endif
```

This ensures that speechKit has already been set up when you create your own capture session in viewDidAppear.

SpeechKit delegate method `recognizerDidFinishRecording` is called  when the recognizer stops recording audio. It is automatically called when a silence is detected, or manually called when you do `[voiceSearch stopRecording]`. When this happens, your own recording has not finished, it needs time to save the audio file to disk, and the error message says all i/o should stop prior to deactivating an audio session. You can see a log by the sdk `release audio session 1`, which I think is deactivating a session and release it. So I think you should add this in the above method.

```
[[self.session.outputs[1] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] setEnabled:NO];
```

The output is `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` you set up earlier, and connection is an audio connection, doing this seems to make the error disappear.

Comment: I think the OP wants to record and transcribe simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, the original code does simultaneously recording and transcribing, while the recording file fails to save to the device, now it is successfully saved. I have also tested that once `recognizerDidFinishRecording` is automatically called, it will not start to record automatically.

Comment: Yes, I have tested it -- it's a good work-around, but the recorded video does not save audio.  This method means that text can be transcribed *or* audio can be saved, but not both simultaneously.

Comment: Shouldn't be, by the time `recognizerDidFinishRecording` is called, audio has been recorded, the one line code will cause audio file to be saved, as what I have tested, it then goes to play the file with audio.

Comment: In case you ever need it, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znyww4wsnfnclrv/ViewController.m.rtf?dl=0) is the ViewController.m file I used.

Comment: Thank you -- the ViewController helped.  It was my misunderstanding when to disable the output -- I was doing it prior to the session being started.  Once I followed your lead, it worked perfectly!